# Google Sheets: Populate row headers based on unique sorted form responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Form linked to a Sheet. There are two fields used to categorize the rest of the data entered in the form: employee ID (positive, 7-digit integer) and store number (4-char string). There will be a dynamic page on the spreadsheet that generates a "report" summarizing all employee performance metrics from today (or whatever day it currently is).

I need this "report" to have a header row listing the employee IDs for each unique employee who has entered their performance metrics for whatever store is selected (from a data-validated drop-down at the top of the page).

My question is how to do this, as I'm a bit lost. I apologize if the solution is trivial. Here is an example of what I'm looking for...

Form Entries:

```
EMPLOYEE ID     STORE #
-----------------------
1234567         A100
7654321         A100
1234567         A100
9000000         9Z55
3699630         A100
0999999         9Z55
```

Spreadsheet output (range A1:A10 reserved) when Store # A100 is selected:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4:A10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 7654321 | 3699630 | (Blank) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you simply want to extract unique ID's by filtering based on store selected and then transpose. Try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=D1)))
```

Or can use `TOROW()` function.

```
=TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=D1)))
```

[image]